# Jest test react native expo-print import error

Tags: react-native, testing, import, jestjs, expo

I'm trying apply **jest** tests to my **expo** application, but I'm getting a error when running the tests due the expo-print import.

When i remove the expo-print import, the first test that I did runs without problems, but if imported the console shows the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Orientation')
>
> 1 | import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
>
> > 2 | import { printToFileAsync } from 'expo-print';
>
> ```
>  ^
> ```

I try add the expo-print lib to ***transformIgnorePatterns*** in jest config in the ***package.json*** but the problem continues to show.

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|
       expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|
       @unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|expo-print)"
    ]
  }
```

Can someone give me some solution for this problem?